# Golang change type of pointer interface

Tags: go

I have a function which returns a slice of pointers of some interface. I want to change the type later in the code to the implementation type but nothing works, I still get an invalid type assertion.

Example

```
func Test(c Parsable)([]*Parsable, error) {
   // generate slice by factory method on Parsable inteface and return slice
}

var implParsable ImplParsable
results, err := Test(implParsable) 

data := results[0].(ImplParsable) // I tried this in many variations but nothing works
```

Comment: If it's a pointer you just need to dereference it (`*`), but are you sure you actually _want_ to be using a pointer to to an interface? There is usually no ready to do so.

Comment: I try it also with * but not working, and I have function where I use it as factory, I add the function for more explanation of problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resultSets[0]` is a pointer to an interface, so you need to dereference that pointer to get the interface value, which you can do inline since slice values are addressable.

```
data :=  (*resultSets[0]).(ImplParsable)
```